# Connect to Tornado app in Docker

Tags: python, docker, tornado

In **Dockerfile** I use:

```
EXPOSE 8888
```

So, I run the container:

```
docker run --name some-app --link some-redis:redis -d app
```

In output I have this string:

```
c980349b5b2120064fc197b00a1aaf94aa16c788b66cb148da7826bb5488d0db
```

Then I want to know the ip, that I can connect from browser:

```
docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' c980349b
5b2120064fc197b00a1aaf94aa16c788b66cb148da7826bb5488d0db
```

It returns **172.17.0.20**

I go to web-brouser and on page `http://172.17.0.20:8888`, but I have in Chrome

```
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

Whats the problem and how to fix that?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM python:3.4.3-slim
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY app.py /usr/src/app/
COPY requirements.txt /usr/src/app/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD [ "python", "./app.py" ]
EXPOSE 8888
```

When I use:

```
docker exec -it some-app bash
netstat -tulnp | grep 8888
```

It returned:

```
bash: netstat: command not found
```

And

```
docker logs some-app
```

Returns nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would check twice the image because it seems that the container has not any process listening on port 8888. To debug the issue you can run a shell session inside the container and check the if the process is listening, check the container log or any file inside if there is any log you can check,... I.E.:

```
   $ sudo docker logs some-app (check container log)
   $ sudo docker exec -it some-app bash  (run an interactive shell)
   # netstat -tulnp | grep 8888   (check if any process is listening)
```

If you don not see the problem I would ask you to post your app Dockerfile and 
 Apart from that you don't need to use `EXPOSE 8888` in your Dockerfile if you use the container ip to access your service. `EXPOSE` is used to enable those port to be published to random ports of the host machine, when the container is run with `-P` option.

Comment: You will need to make some debugging of your container: running directly `python app.py`, installing netstat and check if the process is listening...

Comment: I use `docker run --name some-app -p 8888:8888 --link some-redis:redis -d app` and it works. Thanks!